# Javascript toLowerCase() performance versus variable creation

Tags: javascript, performance

What is more efficient?:

```
var text="ABCdef";
var lowerVersion=text.toLowerCase();
if (lowerVersion=='abcdef' || lowerVersion=='asdfgh' || lowerVersion=='zxcvbn'){...
```

or

```
var text="ABCdef";
if (text.toLowerCase()=='abcdef' || text.toLowerCase()=='asdfgh' || text.toLowerCase()=='zxcvbn'){...
```

i.e. is variable creation more expensive than running toLowerCase() several times?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? http://jsperf.com/

Comment: http://jsperf.com/local-vs-global-2

Comment: This is JavaScript. The answer is going to be: It depends. *(On what engine you're using, on your data, on the other things in the context, on whether the first or last match matches, on alternate Tuesdays...)* The better question is: What's clearer and more maintainable?

Comment: @Felix: Your test is misleading (unintentionally, I'm sure), as both of your tests only call `toLowerCase` once. (You've made the first one match, hence short-circuiting the expression.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: oh :( I just copied and pasted the code actually... updated it.... now the results are different. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @James - thanks, that's a useful site.  Results are here: http://jsperf.com/lowercase-versus-variable  (and thanks T.J.Crowder for adjusting the logic to make the test meaningful)

Comment: The general rule of thumb is: If you have to access a property more than once, store it in a variable.

Comment: wow, the difference is enormous. and so is the difference between the speed of chrome 13 and everything else.

Comment: if you are worried about performance for something like this you should probably not be using JS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is JavaScript. The answer is going to be: **It depends.** It depends on what engine you're using, on your data, on the other things in the context, on whether the first or last match matches, on alternate Tuesdays...

But creating variables in JavaScript is very fast. In contrast, the repeated calls version asks the interpreter to make multiple function calls, and function calls (while fast by any real measure) are slow compared to most other operations. The only way that's going to be as fast is if the interpreter can figure out that it can cache the result of the call, which is tricky.

[Taking @Felix's performance test and making it pessimistic](http://jsperf.com/local-vs-global-2/2) (e.g., worst case and none of them match) suggests that even Chrome can't optimize it enough to make the repeated function calls not come out worse. I didn't do any comprehensive tests, but Chrome, Firefox, and Opera all came out about 60% slower.

You have an alternative, of course:

```
var text="ABCdef";
switch (text.toLowerCase()) {
  case 'abcdef':
    // ...
    break;
  case 'asdfgh'
    // ...
    break;
  case 'zxcvbn'
    // ...
    break;
}
```

All of this is premature optimisation, though, which is bad enough generally but particularly bad with JavaScript and the varying environments in which it runs complicating things.

The better question is: What's clearer and more maintainable?

Answer (score 2):

Caching being faster seems logical (3 `toLowerCase` calls vs one), but the (modern) browsers' scripting engine may well do that for you. I don't think it will matter a lot, if it's a one or few times operation. It may be a question of taste, but I think assigning a variable is more readable/maintainable.

Alternative may be using a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for the check:

```js
var text="ABCdef";
console.log(/^(abcdef|asdfgh|zxcvbn)$/i.test(text) 
   ? `${text} is ok` : `${text} is NOT ok`);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is without any doubt that the 2nd implementation will be significantly faster then the 1st one.

It is for sure that when each time `text.toLowerCase()` will take time like `O(n)` and there will be `3xO(n) vs O(n)`

I have run the test on jsPref.com and the 2nd snippet is 18% faster.

Comment: The second implementation reading top-down would be the one with three calls to toLowerCase(), so I guess you meant the other way around, that the first one is the fastest, assigning the lower case string one time first.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to refer to the value more than once, store it as a variable: toLowerCase() can be very slow with long strings.